# how to auto scroll a text area without increasing its size

Tags: java, netbeans, textarea, panel, jdialog

```
public void NewMessage(){
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter message:");
JTextArea msgBodyContainer = new JTextArea(10,20);
msgBodyContainer.setAutoscrolls(true);
panel.add(label);
panel.add(msgBodyContainer);


String[] options = new String[]{"OK", "Cancel"};
int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "Message "+searchedProfileFirstName,
                         JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                         null, options, options[1]);
if(option == 0) // pressing OK button
{

}
    }
```

that is the code i have used in my defined method NewMessage().
My problem is that I want to prevent this from happening:
[Picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NIde.jpg)

1-as is visible, the text area is automatically anlarging and is not visible past the boundaries of the panel
2-the label "Enter message" moves down to vertically center align itself with the text area

Comment: Put the `JTextArea` into a `JScrollPane`

Comment: i tried doing that, then said panel.addScrollpane and scrollpane.addtextarea stuff
the scrollpane itself doesnt show up in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default
2. Text components like `JTextArea` really should be wrapped in a `JScrollPane` to allow them to become larger than the available space

## Recomendation

- Use a `GridBagLayout` instead, it will give you greater control over the layout
- Use a `JScrollPane` to wrap the `JTextArea` in

For example...

[image: Example]

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter message:");
    JTextArea msgBodyContainer = new JTextArea(10, 20);
    msgBodyContainer.setAutoscrolls(true);
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    panel.add(label, gbc);
    gbc.gridx++;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    panel.add(new JScrollPane(msgBodyContainer), gbc);

    String[] options = new String[]{"OK", "Cancel"};
    int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "Message ",
                                                                                        JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                                                                                        null, options, options[1]);
```

See:

- [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)
- [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

for more details